# Ler String do console em Java

Tags: java

Estou precisando saber como faço para receber Strings que estão sendo impressas no console para fazer algum tipo de tratamento nelas.

Answer (score 3):

Precisa usar a classe [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) e instancia-la passando `System.in` como parâmetro.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Entre com seu nome:");
String nome = scanner.nextLine();
```

Exemplo completo

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Entre com seu nome:");
        String nome = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Seu nome é %s", nome);
    }
}
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/MlFw)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      System.out.println("Entre com seu nome:");
      String nome = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("Seu nome é %s", nome);
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```